# Vue doesn't see updates of my object getting from vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, single-page-application, getter

I have an object in vuex that im getting on the page by getters, but vue see only first update of object. I collect the object stepwise so first it's empty then i have commit that updates vuex state (setUser) and vue showing this new info on the page. But then i use one more commit (addInfo) and it's works I can see updated info using Vue DevTools, but i can't use it on the page it's showing second state

```js
async fetchUser({ commit, state }) {
  return new Promise(() => {
    axiosInstance
      .get(User(), {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        commit('setUser', res.data);
      })
      .then(() => {
        axiosInstance.get(UserID(state.userInfo.pk)).then((res) => {
          axiosInstance.get(res.data.profile).then((res) => {
            commit('addInfo', res.data);
            console.log(state.userInfo);
          });
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
}
```

Object called userInfo im getting on the page by

```js
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['userInfo']),
},
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchUser');
}
```

**This is what i get on the page**
[image: this is what i get on the page]

**This is how the object really looks like**
[image: this is how the object really looks like]

Comment: put your mutation function (addInfo) here please

Comment: and also add your getter function for completeness

Comment: my mutation function:
addInfo(state, additionalInfo) {
      Object.assign(state.userInfo, additionalInfo);
}
my getter:
userInfo: (state) => state.userInfo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common reactivity issue, there are multiple solutions on you'll get used to it:

Basically Vue can not detect property addition on objects due to JS limitations, to solve it your initial `state.userInfo` should have all keys you want to have reactivity, you can just set them to `null`, `''`, or `0` depending on type.

```
userInfo: {
//all my userInfo reactive keys
 1stkey: '',
 2ndkey: null,
 3rdkey: 0,
 ...
 100thkey: '',
}
```

You can also set your `state.userInfo = null` initially to null so you can detect when it gets filled.

Check here for more info of [Vue Reactivity on Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

Comment: I tried all of this and it didn't help. I still have full object in my console, but on the page nothing changed.

Comment: But i tried to do this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 }) as in Vue docs said and it's worked. Thanks a lot!